# .Net Maui app crashing when running on my new 32" monitor

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am working on a .Net Maui app using windows to do the debugging. Recently I upgraded to a 32" 4K (3840 x 2160)

Now, when I try launching the app, I get an immediate exception of :
"Cannot create CanvasImageSource sized 19200 x 83; MaximumBitmapSizeInPixels for this device is 16384."

I assume this is because it is trying to expand the spash.svg? (this is the basic splash screen that VS creates when starting a new maui project)

I have tried adding this to app.xaml.cs:

```
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
    var window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

    int Width = 600;
    int Height = 900;

    window.Width = Width;
    window.Height = Height;

    return window;
}
```

I can see the outline of the window come up at the specified size, but I still get the crash just before the splash normally shows.

Is there a way to fix or fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind, I found out it was due to a 3rd party control (SFDataGrid) causing the error.